# XML Validation error. I would like to know which part is not correct?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
Superstar Movies: Catalog of Movie and Actor Info.
Author: Randy White
Date:   6/28/2011

Filename:         catalog.xml
-->

<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">

<catalog>
<movie movieID="m0100" genre="drama">
    <title>Monster&apos;s Ball</title>
<year>2001</year>
<length>111 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0100 a0102" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0100" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Halle Berry</name>
<date>August 14, 1966</date>
<birthplace>Cleveland, Ohio</birthplace>
<role character="Leticia Musgrove" movie="m0100" />
<role character="Storm" movie="m0101" />
</actor>

<actor actorID="a0102" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Billy Bob Thornton</name>
<role character="Hank Grotowski" movie="m0100" />
</actor>

<movie movieID="m0101" genre="fantasy">
    <title>X-Men</title>
<year>2000</year>
<length>104 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0100 a0103" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0103" oscarWinner="no">
    <name>Ian McKellen</name>
<role character="Magneto" movie="m0101" />
<role character="Gandolf" movie="m0105" />
<role character="Gandolf" movie="m0107" />
</actor>

<movie movieID="m0105" genre="action" earningsRank="17">
    <name>Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring</name>
<date>2001</date>
<length>178 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0103" />
</movie>

<movie movieID="m0107" genre="action" earningsRank="8">
    <name>Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King</name>
<date>2003</date>
<length>201 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0103" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0101" oscarWinner="yes">
<name>Tom Hanks</name>
<date>July 9, 1956</date>
<birthplace>Concord, California</birthplace>
<role character="Captain John H. Miller" movie="m0102" />
<role character="Forrest Gump" movie="m0103" />
<role character="Andrew Beckett" movie="m0104" />
</actor>

<movie movieID="m0102" genre="action" earningsRank="50">
    <name>Saving Private Ryan</name>
<date>1998</date>
<length>170 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0104" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0104" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Matt Damon</name>
<date>October 8, 1970</date>
<birthplace>Cambridge, Massachusetts</birthplace>
<role character="Private James Francis Ryan" movie="m0102" />
</actor>

<movie movieID="m0103" genre="comedy" earningsRank="14">
    <name>Forrest Gump</name>
<date>1994</date>
<length>142 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0105 a0106" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0105" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Sally Field</name>
<birthplace>Pasadena, California</birthplace>
<role character="Mrs. Gump" movie="m0103" />
</actor>

<actor actorID="a0106">
    <name>Gary Sinise</name>
<role character="Lt. Dan Taylor" movie="m0103" />
<role character="Ken Mattingly" movie="m0106" />
</actor>

<movie movieID="m0104" genre="drama">
    <name>Philadelphia</name>
<date>1993</date>
<length>125 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0107" />
</movie>

<movie movieID="m0106" genre="drama">
    <name>Apollo 13</name>
<date>1995</date>
<length>140 minutes</length>
<topBilledActors actorIDs="a0101 a0106" />
</movie>

<actor actorID="a0107" oscarWinner="yes">
    <name>Denzel Washington</name>
<role character="Joe Miller" movie="m0104" />
</actor>
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
File C:\Users\Randy\Documents\XML\Week3\Solution Files\catalog.xml     is not valid.
Content model of element 'movie' disallows element 'name' at this position.
    Error location: catalog / movie / name
    Details
        VC: Element Valid: Content model of element 'movie' disallows element 'name' at this position.
```

Comment: You will need to use a better tool to validate.

Comment: Oh, Well, sicne you could't be bothered to tell us what tool you *are* using...

Comment: Why didnt just ask that.XMLSpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the middle of your XML File starting with "Lord of the Rings" you replaced perhaps accidently the "title" attribute with "name" inside "movies"

Comment: That was part of it. The other part was that I was using year in my dtd file instead of date. I made those changes and it is now working. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to use title instead of name? Try that and if that does not fix errors, can you post the DTD?

Answer (score 1):

to start: try to change `<catalog>` to `<catalog xml:lang="en">`
and close it with `</catalog>` at the end

Comment: Ok I dont follow what your talking about.

Comment: File C:\Users\Randy\Documents\XML\Week3\Solution Files\catalog.xml is not valid. Element 'catalog' has no declaration for an attribute named 'xml:lang'. Error location: catalog / @xml:lang Details VC: Attribute Value Type: Element 'catalog' has no declaration for an attribute named 'xml:lang'.

Comment: @user770022 Your xml file was incomplete and consequently was missing the close tag for catalgo. @Thijs was probably referring to that

Answer (score 1):

After the two first movies, where you use `title`, you start using `name` instead.